# Spring Boot 2.0 Integration Test for JmsTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, testing, integration-testing, solace

I have a very simple MessageHandler class that thanks to Spring Boot works at runtime with just the following lines of code and config:

msg handler

```java
    @Component
    public class MessageHandler {

        @JmsListener(destination = "${solace.jms.queueName}")
        public void processMsg(Message msg) {
            MessageHeaders hdrs = msg.getHeaders();
            etc...
```

main class

```java
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

config

```
    solace.jms.client-name=eeeee
    solace.jms.client-password=dddd
    solace.jms.client-username=ccccc
    solace.jms.msg-vpn=bbbb
    solace.jms.host=smf://aaaaa.xx.yy.com:8000
    solace.jms.queueName=ffffff
```

full pom

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>blah</groupId>
    <artifactId>blahblah</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>blah.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <cucumber.version>2.3.1</cucumber.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.solace.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>solace-jms-spring-boot-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.solace.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>solace-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.197</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sybase</groupId>
            <artifactId>jconn4</artifactId>
            <version>16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What I'm looking for now is how to test this at compile time. Specific questions I have are how to Autowire the JmsTemplate as a mocked instance and what configuration values I should use in the test app properties.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [JMS mock tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/advanced/advanced-testing-examples/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/advance/testing/jms/JmsMockTests.java) which are part of the advanced testing examples for Spring Integration.  Note that this differs from integration testing (despite the name), which involves connecting to an actual broker.  The mock tests don't involve any broker (external or embedded), and include both valid and invalid message testing.

As an alternative, you can use Spring Cloud Stream to process messages. This is an easier / newer way to build event-driven Spring Boot microservices and avoids having to write boilerplate messaging code such as when using `JmsTemplate`.  There's a [binder](https://github.com/SolaceProducts/spring-cloud-stream-binder-solace) available for the Solace broker.  Moreover, you can also mock a `MessageHandler` and test in a manner similar to the Spring Integration samples noted earlier.  See [this article](https://spring.io/blog/2017/10/24/how-to-test-spring-cloud-stream-applications-part-i) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use embedded ActiveMQ instance broker for testing.

From [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-activemq):

> When ActiveMQ is available on the classpath, Spring Boot can also configure a ConnectionFactory. If the broker is present, an embedded broker is automatically started and configured (provided no broker URL is specified through configuration).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! But now I have both solace-jms-spring-boot-starter and spring-boot-starter-activemq dependencies. I can mark the activemq with scope test, but i cannot mark the jms with scope runtime. How do i tell Spring Boot to use the MQ dependency if available?

Comment: it's hard to discuss when you don't show your maven pom file.

Comment: apologies, it is quite large, but added now